# can Portable.Licensing Library be used in an environment with no internet access?

Tags: c#, .net

I watched the Licensing course on pluralsight and large part of the course was about library called portable.licensing.
I want to know can i use this library for offline license check because my application will be used in an environment with no internet access.

Comment: you'll need pass a file to the customer, if not by internet, by usb/mail/etc.